# Where can I ask questions about project size estimation?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to add Facebook logins to my site. I have no idea if this would be 100 or 1000 lines of code.

Where do I ask question of this sort?

How about project management?

https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/ask

Comment: This is not on topic anywhere on the network. It's too localized

Comment: How it too localized, nearly every major site has facebook logins.  The process of doing this has probably been done many, many times.  I thought this would be an easy straight forward and easily answerable question.

Comment: @pure_code.com And a project estimate is going to be dependant on a *lot* of different factors.  It will vary widely for different sites/organizations/programming teams/etc.  If you don't include all of the needed information it's not answerable, and if you do it will have become too localized.

Comment: @Pekka I would say it's too broad, not TL.

Comment: @Undo If you don't include much beyond what the example question here states then yes, it's too broad, as there are too many factors not listed; an answer would requite describing how each factor not described would influence the result, and that's just too much.  It would be TL if enough detail was given to actually make it answerable.

Comment: We don't do estimates for unknown jobs, and no one serious ever will. Only the person who's going to implement the task can make a good estimate.

Comment: (...or who's bidding to get the job, of course)

Comment: @Pekka웃 RE: `Only the person who's going to implement the task can make a good estimate`: I'm the one who implements things for my work, but my estimating skills are piss poor, so this isn't always the case :p

Comment: @Danny I know the problem. One should usually double or triple any estimate you come up with :)

Comment: @Pekka웃 Haha, that's actually exactly what I've learnt to do!

Answer (score 7):

The answer is probably "nowhere" (on the StackExchange network). It's either not going to have enough details and therefore be "not constructive", as it would be open to discussion, opinion, etc. Or it would have all of the details and therefore be "too localized" (as well as potentially still "not constructive") since it's unlikely anybody else would have exactly the same project specifications.

Answer (score 4):

While I wouldn't ask folks to estimate that specific task on a Stack Exchange site, I think there's certainly a more generally worded question here.

Ask a general question about techniques used in software estimation instead. Something along the lines of "I need to integrate a third-party plugin into my application. How should I approach estimating how much work it's going to take?". (But, you know, with some more detail.)

The answers would probably be along the lines of "identify what parts of your app would have to be modified, what UI changes you'll need, etc."

I think a question like that would be a reasonable fit for [Programmers](http://programmers.stackexchange.com), if it hasn't been asked there already.

Answer (score 3):

I would try writing it and seeing how long it is. `</snark>`

Really, the only way to know how many lines something like that is going to be is to try it. While somebody may be able to answer your question, it's bound to be too localized, since it's not a very useful piece of information.

The second reason it's too localized is because very few people are going to look into how many lines of code a project is going to be. Project estimation is more complex than just the number of lines of code, making this statistic fairly meaningless in a general sense.

Answer (score 3):

Hmmm... That's a hard one, because:

- Stack Overflow doesn't accept 'I want to do this' type of questions
- I'm not sure about Programmers, but I bet it would be either off-topic or too broad there.
- You kind of have to have code or Code Review.

So, no site on the Stack Exchange network would probably accept your question. You would be better off Googling 'add Facebook login ' - that should pull up some stuff.